# Ofstream doesn't write in the files?

Tags: c++

So I am trying out the library fstream, and I wrote the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
 ofstream cout;
 cout.open("out.txt");
 cout<<10<<endl;
 cout.close();
}
```

But nothing is getting written in out.txt

I fail to understand because this is very trivial, and I'm not able to figure out why this is not working.

I want to understand how do I start debugging this issue.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I did. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Worked on my machine.  Generated one warning about `cout` being shadowed, but that wasn't a breaking issue.

Comment: *"nothing is getting written"* Do you mean the file is empty, or it doesn't get created at all?

Comment: The code is fine, though a bit inelegant. Anyhow, where would you expect the file to be written? Try supplying a full path and then search for the file there. Alternatively, search for the file in different locations.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have already created the file. Nothing gets written in it.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Both the files, the main file and the output file are in the same path.

Comment: @aroma If you delete the `out.txt`file does it get created? Maybe the working directory is set to a different path then you expect.

Comment: The file may as well be write-protected. Or the directory where the code is trying to create the file. You check the streamstate to see if opening the file succeeded. In any case, one important thing to improve in your way of questioning is that you need to report observations, not your interpretations. "nothing is getting written" is an interpretation. "I opened the file and the editor din't display anything" is an observation.

Comment: why you name it cout when you are using "using namespace std;"
did it print 10 in out put console? maybe it is using std:: cout

Comment: @aroma You don't need to create the file, it will be created automatically. But it should work even if the file already exists. *"Both the files, the main file and the output file are in the same path"* Normally the file will be created in the same directory as your `.exe`, but if you're running it using an IDE, it might be created in a different location.

Comment: @HolyBlackCatcI deleted the file and ran the code again. I couldn't find it anywhere. I'm using sublime text so yeah, i feel like there's some issue with my system.

Comment: So it worked, the file was getting written in some other location that I found out about now. Thanks @HolyBlackCat